# Показать главную форму после скрытия

Tags: c#, winforms

У меня есть две формы (`Form1`, `Form2`). `Form1` появляется сразу после запуска программы, является основной и запускается через `Application.Run(new Form1())`. Мне необходимо реализовать переход от `Form1` к `Form2` и наоборот, но чтобы на экране отображалась только одна форма. На формах есть кнопки, переход к `Form2` и возврат на главную форму. Переход на `Form2` осуществлён через:

```
Form1.ActiveForm.Hide();
Form2 frm = new Form2();
frm.Show();
```

Как мне реализовать возврат к главной форме?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Можно передавать ссылку на форму

   ```
   public class AppForm2 : System.Windows.Forms.Form
   {
       public Form ReturnForm;

       public AppForm2()
       {
           this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(300, 300);
           this.Text = "AppForm2";
           Button button = new Button() { Text = "AppForm2" };
           button.Click += button_Click; 
           this.Controls.Add(btn);
       }

       private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           ReturnForm.Show();
           this.Close();
       }
   }

   public class AppForm1 : System.Windows.Forms.Form
   {
       public AppForm1()
       {
           this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(300, 300);
           this.Text = "AppForm1";
           Button button = new Button() { Text = "AppForm1" };
           button.Click += button_Click; 
           this.Controls.Add(btn);
       }

       private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           this.Hide();
           new AppForm2() { ReturnForm = this }.Show();
       }
   }
   ```
2. Можно установить событие на закрытие формы

   ```
   public class AppForm2 : System.Windows.Forms.Form
   {
       public AppForm2()
       {
           this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(300, 300);
           this.Text = "AppForm2";
           Button button = new Button() { Text = "AppForm2" };
           button.Click += button_Click; 
           this.Controls.Add(btn);
       }

       private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           this.Close();
       }
   }

   public class AppForm1 : System.Windows.Forms.Form
   {
       public AppForm1()
       {
           this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(300, 300);
           this.Text = "AppForm1";
           Button button = new Button() { Text = "AppForm1" };
           button.Click += button_Click; 
           this.Controls.Add(btn);
       }

       private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           this.Hide();
           Form form = new AppForm2();
           form.FormClosed += (object s, FormClosedEventArgs ev) => { this.Show(); };
           form.Show();
       }
   }
   ```
3. Можно использовать диалоговое окно

   ```
   public class AppForm1 : System.Windows.Forms.Form
   {
       public AppForm1()
       {
           this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(300, 300);
           this.Text = "AppForm1";
           Button button = new Button() { Text = "AppForm1" };
           button.Click += button_Click; 
           this.Controls.Add(btn);
       }

       private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           this.Hide();
           new AppForm2().ShowDialog();
           this.Show();
       }

   }
   ```
4. Можно написать через ApplicationContext, тогда можно формы не скрывать, а переключаться между ними. В таком случае можно логику перенести в отдельный класс.

   ```
   public class ApplicationManager 
   {
       private static ApplicationContext _context;
       public static ApplicationContext Context 
       {
           get 
           {
               if (_context == null)
                   _context = new ApplicationContext();

               return _context;
           }  
       }

       public static void ShowForm(Form form)
       {
           Form prev = Context.MainForm;
           Context.MainForm = form;

           prev.Close();
           form.Show();
       }
   }

   public class AppForm2 : System.Windows.Forms.Form
   {
       public AppForm2()
       {
           this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(300, 300);
           this.Text = "AppForm2";
           Button button = new Button() { Text = "AppForm2" };
           button.Click += button_Click; 
           this.Controls.Add(btn);
       }

       private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           ApplicationManager.ShowForm(new AppForm1());
       }
   }

   public class AppForm1 : System.Windows.Forms.Form
   {
       public AppForm1()
       {
           this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(300, 300);
           this.Text = "AppForm1";
           Button button = new Button() { Text = "AppForm1" };
           button.Click += button_Click;
           this.Controls.Add(btn);
       }

       private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           ApplicationManager.ShowForm(new AppForm2());
       }
   }

   static void Main()
   {
       Application.EnableVisualStyles();
       Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

       ApplicationManager.Context.MainForm = new AppForm1();

       Application.Run(ApplicationManager.Context);
   }
   ```

В общем-то вариантов, можно придумать другие или улучшить продемонстрированные короткие примеры под свои нужды. В любом случае все сводится к событиям или ссылкам на форме, отельный интерес представляет только ApplicationContext.

Comment: Попробую разобраться, надеюсь достигну нужного мне результата

Comment: А если у меня формы не в одном cs файле, а в нескольких. Я создавал их через(Проект->Добавить форму Windows). То есть соответственно Form1.cs и Form2.cs. Я рассматриваю первый предложенный вариант с ссылкой и не могу использовать поле ReturnForm в коде файла Form2.cs

Comment: Второй и третий вариант мне не подойдут, так как форм позже будет больше и нужны будут переходы со второй формы на последующие. Попробую еще разобрать последний вариант, но пока мало что получается в нём понять.

Comment: @forge456, не имеет разницы, где находятся формы или как они создавались, здесь они представлены в таком виде только для экономии места. Если планируется много форм, то лучше первый/четвертый вариант или UserControl'ы как еще добавили ниже. Хотя может в первом надо использовать явно свойство `public Form ReturnForm {get; set;}`, хотя не думаю, что проблема в этом.

Comment: В общем долго копался и не мог понять, почему я не мог использовать поле ReturnForm, нашел ошибку. Всё работает. Благодарю. Я просто банально не там пытался использовать данное поле.

Answer (score 1):

Для WinForms (для WPF не уверен, поправьте если ошибаюсь) можно вообще отказаться от отдельных форм в приложении, за исключением диалогов и дочерних форм открывающихся не вместо, а вместе с основной.

Для этого нужно наполнение форм (включая основную) поместить в `UserControl`-ы и отображать их в нужной последовательности на основной форме. Из плюсов: формы приложения не прыгают по экрану, логика закрытия приложения находится в одном месте, можно задать единое меню в главной форме для всех дочерних форм-контролов.

Остальное подробно расписал @Alex Krass

Comment: То есть вы предлагаете реализовать создание и настройку форму полностью программно?

Comment: @forge456 если для пользователя ничего не поменяется, то зачем усложнять себе жизнь?

Comment: @forge456 к тому же, `UserControl` не требуется каждый раз создавать заново. Вы можете создать их в конструкторе как форму и использовать там где понадобятся.